# How can i add the table classes in the realtime database from this code

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to create the table classes in the  realtime database in firebase based on the code source below
[image: Firebase DB]

And this is my code to add new record in the database

```
String AllClasses = dataSnapshot.child("staff").child(uid).child("class_ids").getValue().toString();
if(!AllClasses.equals("0")) {
    HasClasses = true;
    String[] myList = AllClasses.split(",");
    SetClassIdsList(myList);

    List<String> ClassNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> ClassTimingsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String currClassID : myList) {
        ClassNameList.add(dataSnapshot.child("classes").child(currClassID).child("class_name").getValue().toString());
        ClassTimingsList.add(dataSnapshot.child("classes").child(currClassID).child("class_timings").getValue().toString());
    }
    String[] ClassName = new String[ClassNameList.size()];
    ClassNameList.toArray(ClassName);
    String[] ClassTimings = new String[ClassTimingsList.size()];
    ClassTimingsList.toArray(ClassTimings);
    SetListVIew(ClassName, ClassTimings);
```

Comment: I fix it thnks  :)

Comment: Post your fix as answer to your question so that other can know what was the wrong